# UINavigationController within UICollectionViewController

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uinavigationcontroller, swift5

Is there a way to put a UINavigationController within a UICollectionViewController? For example like they do it in Instagram. When you go to your profile, you can see your posts and you can also see the posts you are tagged in. The profile is in that case the UICollectionViewController and the switching between posts and tagged posts is a UINavigationController. Or am I wrong? How could I manage to get something similar?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to put a UINavigationController within a UICollectionViewController, it's rather the other way around.
What you see on Instagram profile screen is more like a UISegmentedControl, which tabs show UICollectionViews (posts and tagged posts)

Here's the documentation of UISegmentControl:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol

Here's a very simple code example on how to use it:
https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/create-uisegmentedcontrol-in-swift-programmatically/

Comment: You're a genius! Thanks!! Exactly what I was looking for :)